# template parse error is not a known element (ionic)

Tags: list, ionic-framework, components, expandable

thanks for the help since now!
    I'm having trouble with this problem, i'm doing an expensable list, follow the code from my app.module.ts:

```
        import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { ExpansivoComponent } from '../components/expansivo/expansivo';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    ExpansivoComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)

  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp

  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

this is my code from html page:

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>listacli</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
      <ion-thumbnail item-start>
        <img src="assets/img/listacli.png">
      </ion-thumbnail>
      <h2>My Neighbor Totoro</h2>
      <p>Hayao Miyazaki • 1988</p>
      <expansivo></expansivo>
      <button ion-button clear item-end>View</button>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>

i already tryied a lot of answers from stackoverflow, but anything could help :(
```

this is the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWPYk.png)

If you guys need any code, just ask, thanks !

Comment: just to remember that is in the begging of the component, this component is not yet a expansable list. but it should work if i wrote on <expansivo>hello word</expansivo> on ionic serve!

Answer (score 0):

you have to add your ExpansivoComponent  to the entryComponents

```
    @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    ExpansivoComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)

  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
        MyApp,
        ExpansivoComponent 
      ],
```

Comment: Então, não funcionou, o erro se manteve. Eu ja tinha tentado isso. :(
So it didn't work. I already tryied this.

Comment: can you show the metadata (@component()) from ExpansivoComponent

Comment: put as an answer